# Button gradient not working after ios 12 (Swift 4.2)

Tags: swift, swift4.2

With the coming of ios 12 and swift 4.2 my code is not working anymore. It used to be a gradient from left-to-right, dark purple-to-light-purple button. How can I fix this?

```
// Gives the button gradient values
func setGradientButton(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, x1: Double, y1: Double, x2: Double, y2: Double) {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2)

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}


// Sets UI elements
func setUI(_ label : UILabel, _ button : UIButton) {

    let colorOne = UIColor(red: 119.0 / 255.0, green: 85.0 / 255.0, blue: 254.0 / 255.0, alpha: 100.0)
    let colorTwo = UIColor(red: 177.0 / 255.0, green: 166.0 / 255.0, blue: 251.0 / 255.0, alpha: 100.0)

    button.setGradientButton(colorOne: colorOne, colorTwo: colorTwo, x1: 0.0, y1: 50, x2: 150, y2: 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    button.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Why your gradients locations are `[0.0, 0.0]`?

Comment: Why not? This code piece used to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't assume why your code has worked before, but I see that you got a few problems with your `CAGradientLayer` setup.

At first, the `locations` array. According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462410-locations) this value "*defines the location of each gradient stop*". So if you want your gradient to start with one color and end with another, you need to set your `locations` like that

```
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
```

Another problem is `startPoint` and `endPoint`. Again, from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462408-startpoint):

> The point is defined in the unit coordinate space and is then mapped to the layer’s bounds rectangle when drawn.

So your points values should be between `0.0` and `1.0`. In unit coordinate space `(0.0, 0.0)` is the top-left corner of your view and `(1.0, 1.0)` is the bottom-right. If you want to get a horizontal gradient, you need to set points like that

```
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
```

Hope it helps you.